# Polling asp.net MVC server from an Android client

Tags: c#, android, google-cloud-messaging

After much research and bumping into the wall a couple of times, it's time to ask some questions.

I'm developing a project which is going to send a message from a web client to a server, then the server should notify multiple clients about the update, which should be done in seconds.

First I thought of using GCM notifications, but the user then have to push the notification in order for some code to run on the client (turning on gps and stuff) but my clients don't have time for clicking the notification when it arrives. So it has to be done without user interaction.

Next thing I thought about was if the android client could listen to the c# server and run code when the server had a new message, but I haven't found a working torturial yet. I was looking into GCM again without push, just messages back and forward, but it's getting difficult to get to work. Also sockets was a option, but it also seems really difficult to get to work and I'm not sure if those options are the way to go.

So I was thinking to just let the android have a background service which is polling either a database or a method on my c# server.

Can anybody give me an idea of what is the right option and maybe a link to a tutorial which is a nice step by step thing.

It could be nice if I had the option to also use it on IOS at a later point.

Comment: Just curious if you have access to modify the server-side of the equation. If so, maybe you could build in SignalR for providing real-time, two way communication in your solution. SignalR is supported on Android, iOS, Windows, and even web applications as well. Might be worth a look. http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/11/01/how-to-use-signalr-in-ios-and-android-apps.aspx

Comment: If I use SignalR i have to use Xamarin and code in c# as I see it.. Isn't there a easier, more normal way of doing this?

Comment: Xamarin is not required to use SignalR.

Comment: Okay thats what the tutorial said, im gonna try to look into that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, what you are trying to do can be easily done by one of the following or more ways:

1)Use GCM messages with a Payload! When the mobile client receives the Notification it gets the Payload and proceeds on specific actions. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html - http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html#react

2)Use a `SyncAdapter` and make your app use an `AlarmManager` which will periodically tell to the app to poll the server through the `SyncAdapter` and check for new content. Another way of triggering the `SyncAdapter` is sending a GCM notification like in the first step. http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

Comment: So if its with a payload the background application will not care if the user dont push the notification? Are you sure about this? Can't find the place where GCM tells me this.. also "periodically tell to the app to poll" thats not what i need. Within seconds mate.. like 2-3

Comment: If you need every 2-3 seconds then you should make sure to implement a notification system! GCM are not supposed to always create a Notification in the StatusBar for the user to see! You can send-to-sync messages and so on! read this link please! http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html#react